# Loading gif in ajax call is not working properly, it will get hanging while loading in google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Loading action should not work properly & While loading the page, the page gets hanged for few seconds due to loading action.

code as follows..

```
                      $("#loadingIcon").show();
                      $.ajax({

                               type: "GET",
                               url: "displayCartItems.action",
                               data: param,
                               success: function(result){

                                   $('#cartPage').html(result) ;

                                $("#loadingIcon").hide();
                                  getCartItemPriceDetail(); 
                                  loadCart = false;

                               },

                            });
```

$("#loadingIcon").show() is consist of gif image but it is hanging in web page while loading

please find the image and please provide solution for this
[image]

Comment: what you are talking about man? what page? where is your code. do you get any error messages?

Comment: am not getting any error message. during ajax call am showing gif image in web page but it is hanging the page..could please tell me solution for this.i didnt get any script issue also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to show the image in the ajax `beforeSend`. Also check does the ajax `success` function is running or the `error` function.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "displayCartItems.action",
    data: param,

    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#loadingIcon").show();
    },
    success: function(result) {
        $('#cartPage').html(result);
        $("#loadingIcon").hide();
        getCartItemPriceDetail();
        loadCart = false;
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        console.log(textStatus);
    }
});
```

Comment: thank u lolka_bolka. but the code what i wrote above is working in local server but when i deployed into main server it will get hanging,,

Comment: And what `console.log()` tells to you? I think there will be something with your `displayCartItems.action`. permission, or not found, etc...

Comment: insert a `console.log('success');` in the `success` function, and please notify me, what console says.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand is you want to show animated gif when ajax call is in progress and stop / hide the image when it is completed. I prefer doing this way:

```
 //Assuming loading gif is hidden

      $(function () {

          $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
               $("#loadingIcon").show();
          }).ajaxStop(function () {
               $("#loadingIcon").hide();
          });

      });
```

Regarding you page hang issue, I suspect, ajax is returning an error so the success did not happen. This will cause the image to stay on ( hang issue). To find this you could check the chrome inspect element and check network and verify what response you are getting.